# How to remove menus items from Menu section from WordPress theme customizer

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need to remove menu items from the menu section in the Wordpress theme customizer.  Below are the screen shots:
[image]

I have tried many things, but they didn't work.  I just need to remove menu items from the menu.

```
function remove_unnessory_item_customizer($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->remove_section("themes");
   ///   $wp_customize->remove_section("available-menu-items");

     // $wp_customize->remove_section("content");  
   // $wp_customize->remove_panel("nav_menus");

   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'static_front_page' );
}

add_action('customize_register', 'remove_unnessory_item_customizer', 9999);
```

Comment: To clarify - are you asking how to remove the ability to adjust Menus from the Customizer? Or are you trying to remove only certain post types from being added to a Menu in the Customizer?

Comment: Just I need to Remove the Page Items from the Menus of customizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the above after researching on the net.  Here I have removed the menu items by unregistering the content type.

```
function remove_post_types() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    if ( isset( $wp_post_types[ 'post' ] ) ) {
        unset( $wp_post_types[ 'post' ] );

          unset( $wp_post_types[ 'post' ] );
       return true;
    }
  return false;
}


add_action('init', 'remove_post_types');
```